# DFS in Tree data structure - What is the base case here in this recursive function?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search

(I'm not native speaker. I apologize for my poor English)

If there is a tree like below.

[image]

Each node is an object.

ex) nodeA.data = 23, nodeA.children = [nodeB, nodeC]

If we search this tree in DFS from the root, the result will be

```
23 - 19 - 15 - 22 - 35 - 31 - 38
```

and the code below is an implementation of DFS, which successfully logs the same result as above.

```js
class TreeNode {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = [];
  }
  
  // ... omit  

  depthFirstTraversal() {
    console.log(this.data);
    this.children.forEach(child => child.depthFirstTraversal());
  }
}
```

But I'm curious :

What if the recursive call inside the forEach loop is repeated and finally "child" parameter points to nodeD?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you fear for will not happen.

The `child` variable in the `forEach` callback could only be `undefined` if in a `children` array you have `undefined` values. But that would be an odd thing to do. In reality, when `this` is a leaf node (like node D), it will have an *empty* `this.children` array, and so the `forEach` loop will not make any iterations, and its callback function will not be called.

That is where the base case of the recursion is realised: when `this.children.length == 0`.